# Going back to the old layout

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I logged on to the site today to find the old layout replaced by a much uglier one. Is there any way to go back to the old one - and if not, are they considering implementing an option?

Comment: I also want the old layout with bluish background and the old tabs that are lined above.

Comment: In 2016 this answer helped me: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204016/switch-stack-exchange-sites-interface-to-the-beta-theme/275804 Not sure if it still works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### tl;dr

> Is there any way to go back to the old layout?

No.

---

The new layout is part of a general redesign of all sites across the Stack Exchange network.

See

- [Japanese updated site theme is ready for testing!](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1908/1628)
- [Rollout of responsive design site themes - Tracking post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314979/rollout-of-responsive-design-site-themes-tracking-post)

You are not the only one unhappy with the new design (see the above posts), but as far as I understand the old design will be removed and the new one implemented.

The whole point of the new vanilla design will be that it is easier to maintain (network-wide), so the individual site designs will most certainly not be kept as a separate option, because they are too labour-intensive to maintain and are expected to break with future updates...

Comment: Don't shoot the messenger...